# Does stemming a lemma provide any useful output?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I am currently working with a neural network model that take words and phrases as features in a bag of words style model (i.e. a vector filled with ones and zeros depending if a word or phrase appears in the input data).

To clean some of the words and reduce the number of unique words or phrases that will be input to the model a colleague and I used stemming AND lemmatization with the nltk python module. After I thought about it, this did not seem to make sense, but stemming the lemmas seemed to reduce the number of unique inputs the most, so we ran with it.

My question is, is it harmful to stem a lemma? Would it harm the results? Is there a point to doing this?

I have not found anyone asking a question like this *anywhere* so I am assuming it simply does not make sense.

Comment: Am not sure what you mean by stemming a lemma? A stem often is a non-sensical root like `PorterStemmer().stem('maximum') = maxim`. Whereas lemmatization is much more precise with a pos parameter of course: `WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize("studying", pos="v") = study`. Now how can you stem study; didn't check but it may give studi.

Comment: You are correct, stemming the lemma of studying (study) returns the stem studi. This is essentially what was done to the data for the model. I was asking would doing this hurt results? I understand these are two methods to achieve similar outcomes with lemmatizing being the better option. But what is the outcome of doing both as far as results go? (in a general sense, I don't expect people to tell me how it will affect my specific model)

Comment: I don't see any linguistic use. Have you tried lemmatizing the stem?

Comment: I can't think of any linguistic use off the top of my head, but in this case the number of  unique words was reduced. This must have some effect then? Lemmatizing a stem often doesn't work as a stem is often a non-word, and lemmatizers cannot find the lemma of a non-word *it seems* and just returns the original non-word.

Comment: there you go. So, I think lemmatization makes sense as you can indicate what the pos tag is and get better results.

Comment: I wouldn't say stemming a lemma makes no sense a priori, it depends on the application and/or the way how the model exploits linguistic information. Reducing the unique count might be helpful, as this approach might collapse words like "maximizing" and "maximum". However, there might be collisions of words that don't belong together (can't think of an example, though); if you have too many of the latter kind, it might hurt performance.